# What happens if we use return statement inside Kafka Listener?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka listener that consumes messages in batch. I am also using manual commit. If there is some issue with any one of the messages I am using a return statement and not committing the offset (I want to process all of them again).

My question is -

Is there a side effect of using a return statement inside Kafka Listener?
How long will it take for the same messages to be consumed again?

I am using Spring Kafka with SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message will not be delivered again if you simply do not commit the offset.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078500/lagged-offsets-skipped-after-new-event-is-published-before-max-poll-interval-in/67097399#67097399).

Use a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and throw an exception.

Any return value will be ignored unless the method is annotated with `@SendTo` (for request/reply processing).