# Kafka Consumer how to poll automatically if message is not committed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Kafka consumer where the messages are passed to another application using a HTTP POST call. I am also manually committing the offset using

acknowledgment.acknowledge();

There are some HTTP return error codes where we ignore the error and commit the offsets and there are some error codes where we don't commit the offsets. The issue is that the kafka consumer is polling for the non committed messages only when I restart the consumer. Is there anyway where I can poll for the messages if there are uncommitted messages in the partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078500/lagged-offsets-skipped-after-new-event-is-published-before-max-poll-interval-in/67097399#67097399) for an explanation.

To redeliver a record, you must throw an exception, in conjunction with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, which repositions the unprocessed partitions so they are fetched again on the next poll.

Or you can `nack()` the acknowledgment to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Thank you  @Gary, This helps. Also lets say that you have 5 messages in the batch(I am using MANUAL_IMMEDIATE) and the 3rd one is failing. Is there anyway to process message 4 and 5 and in the next poll try message 3 again?

Comment: No. You must start at 3 again. Kafka does not ack individual records, it just maintains a committed offset.

Comment: However, the new non blocking retry mechanism in 2.7 might be what you need https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic